How to Remove Stopwords from a Polars DataFrame Column Using SpaCy-GPU?
I'm working with a Polars DataFrame and I want to remove stopwords from a specific column using SpaCy with GPU support. I have the following setup:
import polars as pl
import spacy

# Load SpaCy with GPU enabled
spacy.require_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  # Load the SpaCy model

# Sample Polars DataFrame
df_cleaned = pl.DataFrame({
    "TITLE": ["This is a title", "Another title", "Sample title"]
})

I know how to use SpaCy to remove stopwords in a Pandas DataFrame, but I want to keep everything in Polars. The main issue is that I can't seem to apply custom functions to Polars DataFrames the same way I do in Pandas.
Here's what I've tried:
def remove_stopwords(text):
    doc = nlp(text)  # Process the text with SpaCy
    return " ".join([token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop])  # Return processed text

# Attempting to apply the function to the TITLE column
df_cleaned = df_cleaned.with_columns(
    pl.col("TITLE").apply(remove_stopwords).alias("TITLE")
)

However, I'm getting an error stating that the Expr object has no attribute 'apply'.
How can I effectively remove stopwords from a Polars DataFrame column while leveraging SpaCy for text processing? Is there any workaround to apply functions like in Pandas?

This sounds like a straight forward application of pl.Expr.map_elements.
df_cleaned = df_cleaned.with_columns(
    pl.col("TITLE").map_elements(remove_stopwords)
)

